# How to give active class to categories in application.html.erb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, class

I am currently using Twitter bootstrap for front end of website. I'm writing the code for navbar in application.html.erb file. I'm not able to give active class to some of the links. Here is my application.html.erb file.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <title><%= @title %></title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>

    <!-- For third-generation iPad with high-resolution Retina display: -->
    <!-- Size should be 144 x 144 pixels -->
    <%= favicon_link_tag 'apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png', :rel => 'apple-touch-icon-precomposed', :type => 'image/png', :sizes => '144x144' %>

    <!-- For iPhone with high-resolution Retina display: -->
    <!-- Size should be 114 x 114 pixels -->
    <%= favicon_link_tag 'apple-touch-icon-114x114-precomposed.png', :rel => 'apple-touch-icon-precomposed', :type => 'image/png', :sizes => '114x114' %>

    <!-- For first- and second-generation iPad: -->
    <!-- Size should be 72 x 72 pixels -->
    <%= favicon_link_tag 'apple-touch-icon-72x72-precomposed.png', :rel => 'apple-touch-icon-precomposed', :type => 'image/png', :sizes => '72x72' %>

    <!-- For non-Retina iPhone, iPod Touch, and Android 2.1+ devices: -->
    <!-- Size should be 57 x 57 pixels -->
    <%= favicon_link_tag 'apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png', :rel => 'apple-touch-icon-precomposed', :type => 'image/png' %>

    <!-- For all other devices -->
    <!-- Size should be 32 x 32 pixels -->
    <%= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico', :rel => 'shortcut icon' %>

    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>

    <!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-brand">
          <%=link_to image_tag("knowuros-icon.gif", :alt=>"Brand", :class=>"Brand_Image visible-md visible-lg"), home_index_url %>
          <span><%= link_to "Know Your Operating System", home_index_url, :id => "Brand_Text" %><small>One solution to all of your software problems</small></span>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <% Category.roots.each do |category| %>
              <li class="<%= is_active?('')><%= link_to category.name, category, :class => "link_text" %></li>
            <% end %>
            <li class="<%= is_active?('contacts','new') %>"><%= link_to " ContactUs", new_contact_url, :class =>'glyphicon glyphicon-user' %></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <% if auth_user_signed_in? %>
              <li class="<%= is_active?('articles,'new') %>"><%= link_to " NewArticle", new_article_url, :class =>'glyphicon glyphicon-new-window' %></li>
              <li><%= link_to " SignOut", destroy_auth_user_session_url, :method => 'delete', :class => "glyphicon glyphicon-log-out" %></li>
            <% else %>
              <li class="<%= is_active?('auth_users','sign_in') %>"><%= link_to " Login", new_auth_user_session_url, :class => "glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"  %></li>
              <li class="<%= is_active?('auth_users,'sign_up') %>"><%= link_to " Register", new_auth_user_registration_url, :class => "glyphicon glyphicon-registration-mark" %></li>
            <% end %>
            <form id= "search" class="navbar-form">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-search">Search</button>
            </form>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <%= bootstrap_flash %>
        <%= yield %>
      </div><!--/row-->
      <footer>
        <p>&copy; Company 2016</p>
      </footer>
    </div> <!-- /container -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is application_helper.rb file

```html
module ApplicationHelper
  def is_active(controller, action)
    params[:action] == action && params[:controller] == controller ? "active" : nil
  end
end
```

The above code is working for all the links except the links in categories.How can I dynamically give active class to links generated from the categories in nav bar.

```html
<% Category.roots.each do |category| %>
              <li class="<%= is_active?('')><%= link_to category.name, category, :class => "link_text" %></li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Have you considered using the rails method `current_page?` http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-current_page-3F

Comment: Yeah I have tried curret_page? It's not working. I have 2 categories both of them are becoming active.

Comment: Your example layout does not match with your helper. Your helper `is_active` expects 2 parameters, but you provide only one within your layout. Also you call `is_active?` from within your layout, bu your helper is named `is_active`

Comment: I have edited my layout but the problem still exists when I tried is_active?('categories','show') both the links generated by category are active in my layout. I want only one choosen category to be active.